# Peak index in mountain question - Leetcode

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am solving leetcode questions, and I came across this question:

> Let's call an array A a mountain if the following properties hold:
>
> A.length >= 3
>
> There exists some 0 < i < A.length - 1 such that A[0] < A[1] < ... A[i-1] < A[i] > A[i+1] > ... > A[A.length - 1]
>
> Given an array that is definitely a mountain, return any i such that A[0] < A[1] < ... A[i-1] < A[i] > A[i+1] > ... > A[A.length - 1]**

To my understanding, this should return the max value in the array which is in middle of the lower value elements. But, I don't understand this example:

This is the code i wrote:

```
def peakIndexInMountainArray(self, A):
    """
    :type A: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    ini = A[0]
    arr = []
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        if ini < A[i]:
            ini = A[i]
        else:
            fin = A[i]
    return ini
```

and this is one of the examples given:

> Example 2:
>
> Input: [0,2,1,0]
>
> Output: 1

The test case of the above example is failing. Sorry, if this may sound stupid, but I am not sure, what I am doing wrong. Care to explain, someone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to return the index, not the value of the peak.

Comment: @merlyn that totally makes sense. Thanks!